# recipient.Id Is Null : When it is sent from Site.ForgotPassword and System.ResetPassword

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I am using the forgetpassword functionality and added a VF email template , However the values are coming as null.

The VF email template is:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Update Password" recipientType="User">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <p>recipient.id: {!recipient.id}</p>
        <a href="{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}" class="button">Click Here to set your Password</a>  
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

After i found that there is a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SdBfAAK) affecting me here, however when I try use the posted workaround it still didn't work:

The template we're testing with looks like:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Update Password" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Account">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <p>recipient.id: {!recipient.id}</p>
        <p>relatedTo.id: {!relatedTo.id}</p>
        <a href="{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}" class="button">Click Here to set your Password</a> 
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Is there is something wrong going on.The values are still coming as null

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue.